# SSL_new thread safe or not?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I know `SSL_read/write` is not thread safe. However few reference can be found on thread safety of `SSL_new` using the same `SSL_CTX`. As far as I know OpenSSL enables session cache by default, which means race conditions when fetching from this cache. As a result, `SSL_new` may not be thread-safe? And where does this cache locate?

Comment: *"OpenSSL can safely be used in multi-threaded applications provided that at least two callback functions are set..."* - https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/threads.html

Comment: Thanks. To be clear, as long as I set these callbacks, it's safe to call SSL_xxx even on the same SSL object at the same time?

Comment: That's how I would interpret the documentation. Of course, this is the documentation for 1.0.2 so check against the documentation of the OpenSSL version you are using which might be different.